# Is there a tool to navigate targets and properties 's definition?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I'm working on a bundle of MSBuild script files and many many times I have the need of locating the definition of a called target or a property being used. At the moment, I have to search to the target/property 's name text and view the file containing that text - only then I can read the definition of the target/property I'm looking for.

This remind me of the feature of class/variable navigation of Visual Studio: we can choose "Go to definition" or "Find references" when select a class name or a variable. Is there a similar way to work with MSBuild target/property/item?

Hope to hear from all of you!

Nam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two tools that I know of that my help you they are listed below.

- [MSBuild Sidekick](http://attrice.info/msbuild/)
- [MSBuild Explorer](http://www.msbuildexplorer.com/)

Comment: Thank you. I've tried them. Those a handy tool!
But it would be nice if Microsoft put a similar tool inside Visual Studio, right? Do you know if they have plan for that?

Comment: I don't know of any such plan.